# self.property: initializing objects without memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c

I´m using `ARC` and have a strong property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) WebViewController *webViewController;
```

I synthesize it, and initialize it like it

```
//since ARC is used, is this ok?
self.webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc]init];
```

what happens if I keep doing it again, e.G. in the `applicationDidBecomeActive:`

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  self.webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc]init];
  self.window.rootViewController = self.webViewController;
}
```

I´m thinking it must cause a memory leak cause a new instance of `WebViewController` is created every time the app becomes active from background. Do I have multiple instances of it? Or does the old instance gets deleted/released if I "overwrite" `self.webViewController` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you overwrite the property's value, the previous one gets released: internally, its retain count is decreased by one. If there are no more strong references somewhere else, then it gets deallocated.

Comment: so it could cause a memory leak if theres a reference somewhere else, I was hoping I can have clearness after my question, but how do I find out the retain count is set to 0 when I overwrite the property.

Comment: I dont know if this is a sample cor U wrote or not, but just in case u dont need to set root controller on applicationDidBecomeActive nor U have to allocate it again, and U should know where your strong references R in your code

Comment: @dan don't ask for retain count. It is not a good practice and retain count is more complex than that. Think in autoreleased objects. If you want to know if the object is released, just create a dealloc method to set a breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I think the problem is I dont understand how it appears in the code if an object has references somewhere else. I just was curious and found out the function `retainCount` is not allowed in ARC.

Comment: Luckily, "Automatic Reference Counting" should do all that stuff for you. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting